# django render field of a foreignkey field

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I have a model:

```
class Media(models.Model):
olc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
media_files = models.ForeignKey('MediaManager', related_name='media')


class MediaManager(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    media_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and my form:

```
class MediaForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Media
    fields = ("olc", "media_files")
```

Here I get a dropdown for media_files in Media.
Is it possible that I get the fields of MediaManager in Media like

```
fields =  ("olc", "title",  "media_file")
```

and it renders all the field and media_file gives a browse option ?

Any help ?

Comment: You should use a formset to accomplish this. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets